# Display offline pdf with react native using expo

Tags: react-native, pdf, expo

as the title says i was trying to display a pdf file saved on assets folder on react-native using EXPO, any ideas on how to do it?
Now i have a momentary solution that displays a webview of google drive reading the pdf but i wanted to do it offline with the local pdf file
.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Default } from '../layouts';

import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';


function Flujograma({ route, navigation }) {

  const { name } = route.params;

  return (
    <WebView
      source={{uri: 'https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=<ONLINE_PDF_LINK'}}
      style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
  );
}

export default Flujograma;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use expo filesystem to change the uri to a file system uri. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/